# Slim : how to log all request to the framework

Tags: php, slim

I would like to log all requests to my Slim Rest server. 200 ok, 404 errors, etc...

With the following code I can only log Exceptions.  I want to log all the incoming requests.

```
require 'Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

require 'Slim/Extras/Log/DateTimeFileWriter.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim (
    array(
        'debug' => true,
        'log.enabled' => true,
        'log.level' => \Slim\Log::DEBUG,
        'log.writer' => new \Slim\Extras\Log\DateTimeFileWriter(array(
            'path' => '/tmp/slim',
            'name_format' => 'Y-m-d',
            'message_format' => '%label% - %date% - %message%'
        ))
    )
);
```

Answer (score 13):

With slim v3, you [can't use hooks anymore](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/start/upgrade.html#hooks).

Here is the solution I came up with :

#### Add a new middleware

A middleware can be seen as a function which is applied to every incoming request. Therefore, it sort of intercepts every request, allowing us to log everything we need.

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app->add(function (Request $request, Response $response, callable $next) {
    $route = $request->getAttribute('route');
    $this->logger->info($request->getMethod() . ' ' . $route->getPattern(), [$route->getArguments()]);
    $response = $next($request, $response);
    $this->logger->info($response->getStatusCode() . ' ' . $response->getReasonPhrase(), [(string)$response->getBody()]);

    return $response;
});
```

#### Logger settings

Of course, you need to setup the Logger dependency in the container like so

```
$container = $app->getContainer();

// monolog
$container['logger'] = function ($c) {
    $settings = $c->get('settings')['logger'];
    $logger = new Monolog\Logger($settings['name']);
    $logger->pushProcessor(new Monolog\Processor\UidProcessor());
    $logger->pushHandler(new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler($settings['path'], $settings['level']));
    return $logger;
};
```

With the logger settings

```
return [
    'determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware' => true, //VERY IMPORTANT for route logging
    'settings' => [
        // Monolog settings
        'logger' => [
            'name' => 'slim-app',
            'path' => __DIR__ . '/../logs/app.log',
            'level' => \Monolog\Logger::DEBUG,
        ]
    ]
]
```

#### Output

```
[2017-06-18 03:40:19] slim-app.INFO: GET /api/publication/{id:[0-9]+} [{"id":"0"}] {"uid":"6e64305"}
[2017-06-18 03:40:19] slim-app.INFO: 200 OK ["[]"] {"uid":"6e64305"}
```

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you want Response data based on your question:

> 200 ok, 404 errors, etc...

Regardless of whether you want request or response info, you can do what you're wanting to do using [Slim Hooks](http://docs.slimframework.com/#Hooks-Overview).  I can't provide a complete example now, but in **untested, off-the-top-of-my-head code**, it might look like:

```
// slim.after.dispatch would probably work just as well. Experiment
$app->hook('slim.after.router', function () use ($app) {
    $request = $app->request;
    $response = $app->response;

    $app->log->debug('Request path: ' . $request->getPathInfo());
    $app->log->debug('Response status: ' . $response->getStatus());
    // And so on ...
});
```

Comment: where will all the request get logged?

Comment: @VivekSancheti That's based on configuration - you tell the logger where to write files.  The OP's example logs to `/tmp/slim`.

Comment: see mentioned 'path' => '/tmp/slim', . Its root tmp . If you need to log at the same place use `__DIR__ . '/slim.txt'` something like that.